# Different shape/image for leaf nodes in pack layout

Tags: d3.js

I am using a pack layout in d3.js (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pack-Layout) and load in a json file with a parent-child structure.

My question is probably a very trivial one: I would like to append a circle or an image(or maybe a rectangle) depending on whether `d.children` returns `parent` or `child` (where child in basically a leaf node).

This is a bit of the code that appends circles to all nodes:

```
 vis.selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)
.enter().append("svg:circle")
  .attr("class", function(d) { return d.children ? "parent" : "child"; })
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
  .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; });
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a filter function:

```
// if you have children, append a circle
node.filter(function(d){
  return d.children;
})
.append("circle")
.attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; });

// if you don't have children, append a rect
node.filter(function(d){
  return !d.children;
})
.append("rect")
.attr("width", function(d) { return d.r; })
.attr("height", function(d) { return d.r; })
.attr("x", function(d) { return -d.r/2; })
.attr("y", function(d) { return -d.r/2; });
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/aMJy40puHDwWUFW5OOJL?p=preview).

[image]

Comment: This is all I have been looking for! Thank you!